# initializing private property of an object

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Differences between Private Fields and Private Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411048/differences-between-private-fields-and-private-properties)

Let's say I have a class MyClass that has a private property MyProp.
What's the difference between

```
public class MyClass
{
  private int MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class MyClass
{
  private int MyProp = 0;
}
```

What's better to use?
Thanks.

Comment: The first one is a property. The second one is a field.

Comment: A repeat of the same type of question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp
http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Difference between Property and Field in C# 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653536/difference-between-property-and-field-in-c-sharp)

http://csharpindepth.com/articles/chapter8/propertiesmatter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You typically have a combination of a public property and a private field:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _someInt;

    public int SomeInt { get { return _someInt; } set { _someInt = value; } }
}
```

This always you to create an abstraction layer (the public property) for the class data (the private field).  When you create just a property, a private field (I believe) is generated.  Is the private field necessary?  No.  But to explicitly declare it is advisable.  That way within the class, the members utilize the private field.