# Where can I use private properties?

Tags: c#, class, properties, field, private

From what I have learned so far a property should be public and used to access the private fields of a class. What I can not understand is why someone would use a private property and not a private field for something that is used only inside the class itself.

Can someone please explain that to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All the benefits of a property can also be useful in a class. But you don't want access from outside.

Comment: Also see <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411048/differences-between-private-fields-and-private-properties>

Comment: One reason: Guard checks cannot be done with fields but properties can. There are many..

Comment: A private property is useful to, i.e, execute some common task or behavior when getting or setting a value. Of course, this is just one of its advantages over private fields.

Comment: See some reason here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310186/are-there-any-reasons-to-use-private-properties-in-c

Comment: As noted in the comments, the use of private properties for caching values has been *somewhat* superseded by the `Lazy<T>` class.

Comment: It is absolutely *great* for debugging.  With no support for data breakpoints in the debugger, setting a breakpoint on the setter is the next best way.